# when do you use fetch() with SQL and php?

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I am a little confused on when you use the fetch() method and when you do not. Like in this case:

Why do I need the fetch() method here:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Idea_Categories WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
$category = $db->query($query);
$category = $category->fetch();
$category_id = $category['categoryID'];
$category_name = $category['categoryName'];
```

But not here:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM statements WHERE categoryID = $category_id ORDER BY entryID";
$statements = $db->query($query);
```

I use $statements here and it just lists all the statements I have in the database:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($statements as $statement) :?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $statement['topic']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <form action="delete_line.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="<?php echo $statement['topic'];?>" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $statement['categoryID'];?>" /> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                </form>                          
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="product_rate.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="<?php echo $statement['topic'];?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upvote" name="action" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="product_rate.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="<?php echo $statement['topic'];?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Downvote" name="action"/>
                </form>
            </td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is it pdo that you're using?

Comment: i believe so, that's what the book calls it

Comment: Does the second version actually do anything useful?

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: Could you post what does `print_r($statements)` show?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion about security

Comment: but what happens if I don't have the fetch, then what is stored in the variable?

Comment: try using `var_dump($statement);` and see what you get, play around

Comment: your first piece of code looks strange you're overwriting $category (lucky you're probably only returning one row)

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::query` returns a `PDOStatement` object. Any time you are handling a result set with PDO you have such an object. Usually you call `PDOStatement::fetch` on it to get the results, often in a loop like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) ...
```

[`PDOStatement` also implements](http://php.net/PDOStatement) the [`Traversable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) though, which simply enables you to do exactly the same thing as above, but using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) ...
```

It's just a bit of syntactic sugar thanks to the `Traversable` interface, which you can implement in any of your own classes as well.